# Terrain definition question

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, terrain

For the purpose of making an Urban Ranger, does the Urban indoor and outdoor setting/location/place/area/space count as terrain for the purpose of the Rangers *Natural Explorer* ability? I'm using [the revised Ranger from Unearthed Arcana](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/unearthed-arcana-ranger-revised).

Comment: I've added a link to the revised Ranger in question. (To help people find out about it and understand what you mean exactly, and in case they revise it a second time.) If this is the incorrect link, could you update it to the correct one?

Comment: I can't find any wording that refers to specific types of terrain in the class feature. Can you add the particular passage you're worried about?

Comment: To doppelgreener
This the right one and the one I'm currently using. So far I can "RAW" it it just applies to a natural setting and not to urban areas or in or on "man/humanoid" structures. I guess me and the GM should discuss what to take from this and home brew/ house rules a few things that could work in an urban environment.

To Icyfire
Natural Explorer gives various perks when a Ranger is the wild I.E. out doors like the Mountains, Swamp Lands, Deserts and the like.
I'd like to know that if this Ability could work with if the Ranger prefers being in urban or "man made" environment.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Urban Ranger in 5e, including UA. What source do you ask about?

Comment: To enkryptor: I know there is no Urban Ranger per say, I just built a Ranger who just happens to favor and Urban Setting. I chose the background of Urban Bounty Hunters from SCAG (Sword Coast Adventure Guide) and was curious to how much of Natural Explorer's perks would apply to an Urban Setting. Basically think a detective of some sort.

Comment: Please use [edit]s to improve the question instead of just using comments. The question can't be reopened until *it* is clear, and comments on their own don't accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

The *Natural Explore* ability is unrelated to terrain. Unlike the PHB, an UA ranger does not have associations with particular terrain types.

The first 3 abilities function all the time anywhere. The remaining abilities apply when "navigating the wilderness". The relevant Miriam-Webster definition of wilderness is:

> 1
>   a (1) :  a tract or region uncultivated and uninhabited by human beings (2) :  an area essentially undisturbed by human activity together with its naturally developed life community
>
> b :  an empty or pathless area or
>
> c :  a part of a garden devoted to wild growth

On the face of it, urban areas and buildings are *not* wilderness. However, abandoned urban areas and buildings could be.

Comment: I think this correct answer would be an iota better if the first line said something like "is unrelated to terrain *as of UA revision*" or something like that. Given that Natural Explorer used to be related to terrain, and still is in everyone's PHBs, I could imagine someone coming along and being confused. (Only a little, though.)

Comment: You're right about that. Thing is ...Is this current UA Revised Ranger supposed to replace the one in the PHB or errata... ed??? (Sp)